# CSS Overlay with multiple colors on top of image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a DIV block on the top corner of an image that can hold multiple lines of text. Managed to make a overlay on corner of image like below

```css
.sliderImgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: 50px solid #FF0000;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
.overlayImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderImgWrapper">
    <div class="overlay">
      
    </div>
</div>
```

But not sure how can I make the transparency of the image to a light shade on one side of the div. A similar or closer  look is like in  the image

[image]

Also after placing a span to hold text inside the red area like

```
  <div class="overlay">
      <span style="color:blue;">title</span>
    </div>
```

The triangular shape seems to be broken

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without additional markup using pseudo-elements.

```css
.sliderImgWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNFzE.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.sliderImgWrapper:before,
.sliderImgWrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 120px solid #FF0000;
}

.sliderImgWrapper:before {
  border-right: 180px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sliderImgWrapper:after {
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.sliderImgWrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderImgWrapper">
  <span>UNIVERSITY<br>UNIVERSITY<br>UNIVERSITY</span>
</div>
```